# WP-API select custom taxonomy when creating a post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-api

I am using POSTMAN to test out some API Routes using WP-API. I have created a custom post type called timeslot and have associated a custom taxonomy called location to that post type.

When I am trying to create a new post, how can I select the taxonomy term associated with the new timeslot? I have tried submitting the taxonomy ID with the taxonomy name {'location' : 128}, but that does not seem to work.

Attached is a screenshot of how I am posting the query in POSTMAN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same answer, but looking at the [WP REST API documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) it seems you can't do it. In the Create a Post section you'll see the API only accepts these arguments:

- date
- date_gmt
- password
- slug
- status
- title
- content
- author
- excerpt
- featured_media
- comment_status
- ping_status
- format
- sticky
- categories
- tags